# Replace unmatched regex by given input

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I have a string like below.

`update comment for line OBC-1234:Message is this`

I wanted to match `OBC-1234:Message is this` out of the above string.

Regex I used is `\w*-\d+:(\w+\s?)+`

The tool on which I work have only one function which replaces matched regex by some input parameter.
That means it will first match the regex from the string and will replace it by given input.
But my requirement is to replace the unmatched string by the given input.

The output should be like below

`update comment for line input`

I know it can be done through negation but I don't how to use it for a bigger string. Please help.

Comment: what are you using the regex with? What tool?

Comment: Try `^.*?(\w*-\d+:\w+(?:\s+\w+)*)` and replace with `$1` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/jwxQd4/1)).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Sorry there was a mistake in the question. Please look into the updated question.

Comment: `.*?([A-Z\d-]+:[\w ]+)$` works

Comment: @dawg Pelase look into the updated question.

Comment: OK, then `(.*?)(?:[A-Z\d-]+:[\w ]+)$` [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/YRAc0r/2/)

Comment: @dawg Thanks!. It works. But can you please add answer with proper explanation.

Comment: `^(.*?\S)\s*\w+-\d+:\w+(?:\s+\w+)*\s*$` -> `$1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
/(.*?)(?:[A-Z\d-]+:[\w ]+)$/\1New Addition/
                     ^            words and ' ' to end of line
                  ^               literal :
            ^                     character class for OBC-1234 pattern
        ^                         Non capturing group
 ^                                Capture to the LH of description
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/YRAc0r/2/)

If the `OBC-1234` is more concrete, you can do:

```
/(.*?)(?:[A-Z]+-\d+:[\w ]+)$/\1New Addition/
```

to be more specific.

[Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/d3veCW/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Use:

- Find: `^(.*?)\w*-\d+:\w+(?:\s+\w+)*`
- Replace: `$1NEW STRING`

Comment: Answer is correct. dawg answered it first in comments. Hence, accepted other.